# How to trigger a specific gitlab ci/cd job on file change

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, continuous-deployment

I have this file hierarchy as below

```
/
run_docker.sh
Dockerfile
.gitlab-ci.yml
```

And the content of my `.gitlab-ci.yml` is as follows

```
stages:
  - run_script
  - build_image

run_script:
  stage: run_script
  script:
    - echo "script is running"
build_image:
  stage: run_docker
  script:
    - echo "building image"
```

These `script` tags are some examples I have put here (not real values) and **what I want is, I need to trigger only the `build_image` job when I did a change ONLY to the `Dockerfile`** and it **SHOULDN'T** trigger the `build_image` job.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar scenario, and I ended up using the following condition:

```
  only:
    variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /docker/
```

It is not exactly what you wanted, but it can do the job. Whenever I need to trigger docker image building job, I just mention `[docker]` in my commit message.